# repeat(a, repeats) with DataFrame and text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I  have an imported dataframe from an excel file which looks something like this;  [The input data imported with pd.read_excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08xOV.png)

What I want to do is to create a new separate column vector which repeats the 'Event' column by the 'Duration'/30. I.e. something that looks like this;
[What I want the output to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Psb.png)

I can do this easily in MATLAB with the 'repelem' function however I am having problems with getting 'repeat' to work with dataframe and non-int's.

```
# Broken Python attempt 
new_df = np.repeat(df.Event, df.Duration)
```

Comment: Yes, it is correct to use `np.repeat(df.Event, df.Duration)`, like `repelem(Event, [30 60 60 120 60 60])` in Matlab, what's the issue?

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557